# validate if table row has data in every fields

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to validate if a current row in every field has data on it and if it has not then display no data. Please help me. Also it is advisable to use echo in displaying the table data or should i stick to the html. Thanks in advance! I've been searching the net and was not able to find some answers. lol

```
$ct_list = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from ct LEFT JOIN station on ct.station_id=station.station_id LEFT JOIN dilg_emp on dilg_emp.station_id=station.station_id where dilg_emp.dilg_emp_id= $session_id"); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($ct_list) > 0){
    while ($ct_row_list = mysqli_fetch_array($ct_list)) {
        $ct_FName = $ct_row_list['ct_FName'];
        $ct_MName = $ct_row_list['ct_MName'];
        $ct_LName = $ct_row_list['ct_LName'];
        $ct_SName = $ct_row_list['ct_SName'];
        $ct_address = $ct_row_list['ct_address'];
        $ct_birthday = $ct_row_list['ct_birthday'];
        $ct_age = $ct_row_list['ct_age'];
        $ct_gender = $ct_row_list['ct_gender'];
        $ct_level_educ = $ct_row_list['ct_level_educ'];
        $ct_course = $ct_row_list['ct_course'];
        $ct_school = $ct_row_list['ct_school'];
        $ct_prev_covid = $ct_row_list['ct_prev_covid'];
        $ct_training_date = $ct_row_list['ct_training_date'];
        $ct_deployment_date = $ct_row_list['ct_deployment_date'];
        $ct_prev_emp = $ct_row_list['ct_prev_emp'];
        echo "<tr>
            <td>".
        $x++."
            </td>
            <td>
                $ct_FName $ct_MName $ct_LName $ct_SName
            </td>
            <td> 
                $ct_address
            </td>
            <td> 
                $ct_birthday
            </td>
            <td>
                $ct_age
            </td>
            <td>
                $ct_gender
            </td>
            <td>
                $ct_level_educ
            </td>
            <td>
                $ct_course
            </td>
            <td>
                $ct_school
            </td>
            <td>
                $ct_prev_covid
            </td>
            <td>
               $ct_training_date
            </td>
            <td>
                $ct_deployment_date
            </td>
            <td>
                $ct_prev_emp
            </td>
        </tr>";
    }
}else{    
    echo "<tr><td><b>Nothing to display</b></td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: What is not working?  Do you mean if any columns in the row are empty then don't display the row or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the row array, replacing empty values with `No data`.

```
$optional_fields = ["ct_SName"];
while ($ct_row_list = mysqli_fetch_array($ct_list)) {
    foreach ($ct_row_list as $name => &$value) {
        if (in_array($name, $optional_fields)) {
            continue;
        } elseif (empty($value)) {
            $value = "No data";
        }
    }
    // rest of your code goes here
```

Comment: Thanks its working. If I would exclude 1 field in a row. sample the $ct_SName. How will I do it?

Comment: Use an `if` statement to skip that field.

Comment: where would i put it the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you mean, if a row has any empty columns then skip that row?

If you select 15 columns in the query or if you know that `SELECT *` will return 15 columns, then filter out the empty ones and see if there are 15:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($ct_list) > 0) {
    while ($ct_row_list = mysqli_fetch_array($ct_list)) {
        if (count(array_filter($ct_row)) == 15) {
            echo "<tr>
            <td>$x++</td>
            <td>$ct_FName $ct_MName $ct_LName $ct_SName</td>"; //etc...
        }
    }
}
```

You could also check and skip:

```
        if (count(array_filter($ct_row)) < 15) {
            continue;
        }
        //echo your HTML
```